PowerShell script for automated Windows health check and repair
I've been experiencing frequent issues with my Windows operating system, requiring me to manually run various system health and repair commands (such as DISM, sfc, and chkdsk) several times per week. To streamline this process, I've created a PowerShell script that automates the inspection, diagnosis, and repair of common Windows issues.
The script progresses from simple to more complex checks, only performing repairs when necessary, and prompts for a system restart only if absolutely required. I'm looking for a review of this script to ensure it's efficient, follows best practices, and effectively addresses the problem.
Script
# Windows Health Check and Repair Script

# Debug mode (set to $true to see full command outputs)
$DebugMode = $true

# Function to check if the script is running with administrator privileges
function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

# Check for administrator privileges
if (-not (Test-Admin)) {
    Write-Host "This script requires administrator privileges. Please run PowerShell as an administrator." -ForegroundColor Red
    Exit
}

# Function to run a command and return its output
function Run-Command {
    param (
        [string]$command,
        [string]$arguments
    )
    $output = & $command $arguments.Split(" ")
    if ($DebugMode) {
        Write-Host "Debug: Full output of '$command $arguments':" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        $output | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Gray }
    }
    return $output
}

# Variables to track if repairs were made and if a restart is needed
$repairsMade = $false
$restartNeeded = $false

# Step 1: Run DISM to check for and repair any component store corruption
Write-Host "Step 1: Checking component store health with DISM..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

# DISM CheckHealth
$dismCheckOutput = Run-Command "DISM.exe" "/Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth"
if ($dismCheckOutput -match "No component store corruption detected.") {
    Write-Host "Component store is healthy." -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "Potential component store issues detected. Running ScanHealth..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    # DISM ScanHealth
    $dismScanOutput = Run-Command "DISM.exe" "/Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth"
    if ($dismScanOutput -match "Component store corruption detected.") {
        Write-Host "Component store corruption confirmed. Attempting repair..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # DISM RestoreHealth
        $repairOutput = Run-Command "DISM.exe" "/Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth"
        if ($repairOutput -match "The restore operation completed successfully.") {
            Write-Host "Component store repaired successfully." -ForegroundColor Green
            $repairsMade = $true
        } else {
            Write-Host "Failed to repair component store. Please check the logs for more information." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "No component store corruption detected after scan." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}

# Step 2: Run System File Checker (SFC)
Write-Host "`nStep 2: Running System File Checker..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

# First, run sfc /verifyonly
$sfcVerifyOutput = Run-Command "sfc" "/verifyonly"
if ($sfcVerifyOutput -match "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.") {
    Write-Host "No system file integrity violations found." -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "Potential system file integrity violations detected. Running full scan and repair..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    # Run sfc /scannow if violations were found
    $sfcScanOutput = Run-Command "sfc" "/scannow"
    if ($sfcScanOutput -match "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.") {
        Write-Host "Corrupt system files were found and repaired." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $repairsMade = $true
    } elseif ($sfcScanOutput -match "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.") {
        Write-Host "No system file integrity violations found after full scan." -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host "System File Checker encountered an issue. Please check the logs for more information." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

# Step 3: Check disk health
Write-Host "`nStep 3: Checking disk health..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$systemDrive = $env:SystemDrive
$chkdskOutput = Run-Command "chkdsk" "$systemDrive /scan"
if ($chkdskOutput -match "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.") {
    Write-Host "No file system errors detected." -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
    Write-Host "File system errors detected. Scheduling a full chkdsk on next restart." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $chkdskFixOutput = Run-Command "chkdsk" "$systemDrive /f /r /x"
    $restartNeeded = $true
}

# Summary and restart prompt
Write-Host "`nHealth check and repair process completed." -ForegroundColor Cyan
if ($repairsMade) {
    Write-Host "Some repairs were made to your system." -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

if ($restartNeeded) {
    Write-Host "A restart is required to complete the repair process." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $restart = Read-Host "Do you want to restart your computer now? (Y/N)"
    if ($restart -eq "Y" -or $restart -eq "y") {
        Restart-Computer -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "Please remember to restart your computer as soon as possible to complete the repair process." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No restart is required at this time." -ForegroundColor Green
}

Specific areas I'm looking for feedback on:

Efficiency: Are there ways to make this script run faster or use fewer resources?
Error handling: Have I adequately addressed potential error scenarios?
Best practices: Are there any PowerShell best practices I should be following that I'm not?
Completeness: Are there other important system health checks or repairs I should include?
User experience: Is the output clear and informative for users of varying technical levels?
Safety: Are there any potential risks or unintended consequences I should be aware of?

